# Is it possible to display two categorical symbolizes for two different attributes in one layer alongside each other in ArcMAP 10.1?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, vector, visualisation

I have a road layer that I would like to display attribute_1 = "speed" on top of the line segment and attribute_2 = "traffic_volume" below the line segment.

For each attribute I would like to setup speed bins 0-30, 30-40, 50-60, 60+ and for volume bins: 0-200, 200-1000, 1000-3000, 5000-10000, 10000+

As a rough Schematic, red represents speed, and black represents volumes and the road should run between those two symbols:

[image: Displaying the two symbologies for one road layer]

**Question: I know how to display each attribute as symbol; however, I'm not sure what's the best way to display both symbologies so that they don't overlap**

Note that I'm open to using ArcPY

Comment: Add the layer two times add have one line a lot thicker. Then put it under the first copy of the layer, which is displayed as a thinner line.
 Or you could work with displacements, not exactly sure how that works with lines on the top of my head though..

Comment: @Martin I thought about that, but the two issues where there are a lot of roads, and having very thick lines means that lines are just going to get dissolved and the other issue is that since the two variables are not related; you could have layer_a on top of layer_b or vice verse thus hiding the information below it.

Comment: Yes, that would be a downside. Looks like displacement only is available for points, so that's no way to go either.

Comment: @Jens I found it worked best when the offset is half the line thickness

Comment: @RyanDalton I had deleted my comments so Jens can post a full comprehensive answer and had asked him to delete his comments as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to use a separate line offset for each class.

If you want to display attribute *speed* as *thin blue line* to *red thick line* and display attribute *volume* as *thin white line* to *black thick line*: You have to adjust color, width of line and offset of line for each class separately. E.g. for your 5 *speed* classes you have to set 5 different colors, width of line and offset of line.

In Symbol Property Editor you have to use a Cartographic Line Symbol. On Line Properties tab you can set a offset for Cartographic Line Symbol.

It should work best the offset is half the line thickness.